# Kohana 3.3 Changing url

Tags: request, kohana

I have route

```php
$c_i18n = Kohana::$config->load('i18n');

$allowedLangs = implode('|', array_keys((array)$c_i18n->allowedLangs));
$allowedLangs = "(?i:$allowedLangs)";
$defaultLang = $c_i18n->defaultLang;


Route::set('default', '(<lang>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))', array(
    'lang' => $allowedLangs,
))
    ->defaults(array(
        'lang' => $defaultLang,
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action' => 'index',
        'id' => NULL,
    ));
```

How can I don url with language by default

For example user go: *sait.com* and it will be every time *sait.com/en*
or *sait.com/news -> sait.com/en/news*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
Route::set('default', '(<lang>/)(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array(
    'lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}',
))
->defaults(array(
    'lang' => 'en',
    'controller' => 'main',
    'action' => 'index'
));
```